# Is there any way to block a workbook from "external" access?

Tags: vba, excel

first time asking something here, so I'll apologize beforehand in case I do anything I shouldn't do.

I'm working on a workbook and there are some information in it that shouldn't be available to everyone else, save a few users.
While doing some testing around I've found that it was possible to use another instance of Excel, i.e. another workbook, to access that information (in this case, using VBA).
What I want to know is: is it possible to block another instance of Excel or another workbook from accessing this workbook with the information I want to protect?

The point of this sheet in working on is to be used as a 'database' of sorts for performance feedback of other employees. They fill a form with their self evaluation and then their manager also fill it, evaluating them. All this is stored in a sheet, which is hidden (veryhidden, to be more specific). Using a simple login system, I was able to enable access to this sheet to only one user (one with admin privileges), but assuming someone knows the existence of that sheet, it would be perfectly possible for them to, for example, just copy everything from that sheet to a blank sheet in a new workbook.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to achieve is some kind of restriction in this workbook, allowing only it's own subs and functions to work on it

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Added some info. Hope that helped clarify my problem

Comment: Make sure your logic isn't explicitly VBA based, because users can open it and force macros to be disabled by holding the shift key...

Comment: Without explaining how you currently plan to hide this information from "outside" users, where it's located, how it's protected etc, it's very hard to offer any suggestions.

Comment: @TimWilliams fair enough. I'll edit my post to add some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is encryption. As far as I know Excel only supports one form of encryption, full workbook encryption. In that case there is a password to open the workbook, a user either has access to the full workbook or none at all.

Any other form of encryption in Excel, protected cells, passwords on macros, etc. can all be bypassed easily by a knowledgable user.

However, you could achieve this using either an external database server or implementing your own encryption scheme in the workbook.

There is some information [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84d49593-2d8e-4e7c-af3a-61882af9557d/access-to-cryptencrypt-cryptoapiwinapi-functions-in-vba?forum=isvvba) on howto access the Windows CryptoAPI from VBA.

Comment: Didn't know about the CryptoAPI. Looks interesting though.